# Python manage.py runserver gives error of raise ImportError('win32 only') ImportError: win32 only, using python 3.9, elementary OS 5.1.7 Hera

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, pywin32, python-3.9

I'm new to Django, creating my first project. everything was working fine and suddenly got an error of ImportError('win32 only') ImportError: win32. Searched a lot online but didn't find a solution.

try to install pip install pywin32, got an error

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pywin32

try to install pypiwin32, got error as below,

Collecting pypiwin32
Using cached pypiwin32-223-py3-none-any.whl (1.7 kB)
Using cached pypiwin32-219.zip (4.8 MB)
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [7 lines of output]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 2, in 
File "", line 34, in 
File "/tmp/pip-install-e3895f2v/pypiwin32_a7f6ac392d7c456a8f054610add7c850/setup.py", line 121
print "Building pywin32", pywin32_version
^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print("Building pywin32", pywin32_version)?
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

Nothing working and do not know how to solve this, and what did I do wrong, as it was working fine one second and next to its crashed,  Can anybody please help?

[image]

Comment: You are using PyWin32 (a Windows API wrapper), on an Ubuntu (Linux) system?

Comment: No, I'm not using pywin32 at all, neither had installed, but still getting this error and unable to find solution or what got me into this

Answer (score 0):

im quoting from https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/ "This is the readme for the Python for Win32 (pywin32) extensions, which provides access to many of the Windows APIs from Python". And you dont have any windows api's available because you are on linux.

Comment: yes, but I still got this error on Linux, so do I have to install pywin32? or will it lead me to more problem?

Comment: this might be auto import but your problem seems to be , from asyncio.windows_events import NULL , because if you check that file error you get is raised in line 5, in your import NULL=0, so you can try to remove this import and create a variable like NULL = 0 and use it.